# Can the Google+ app be installed on an iPod Touch?

Tags: ipod-touch, ios, applications, windows, google

I have a 3rd generation iPod touch with iOS upgraded to version 4.3.3. When installing the Google+ 1.0.1 app, it gives the message shown in the picture below.

[image]

*Question: Is there a generation or iOS version of iPod touch that will allow the Google+ app to be installed?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not today.

It looks like the current app asks iTunes to require ***GPS on iPhone***.

iPod Touch and even iPad with GPS are prevented from downloading the app directly and iTunes will not install it.

I don't know why iTunes doesn't tell you what specific devices the app ***will*** work on rather than be a little vague about "not compatible with this device".

[image: iTunes message]

[image: iOS store message]

Comment: I have the Verizon iPad 2 and it doesn't show up in my app store search at all. Installed fine on my iPhone 4

Comment: Excellent - I'll edit my answer with that info - really appreciate checking and sharing:-)

Comment: Lol ok. I'll copy my comment to an answer.

Comment: @bmike Thanks. Seems like just iPhones with GPS then.

Comment: Just realized they don't differentiate people with the same name on here

Comment: Yeah - thomas 50 and thomas 6570 together had me going there for a moment :-)

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to install the app using the [iPhone Configuration Utility](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL851). You first need to download Google+ using iTunes, then use the Configuration Utility to add the .ipa file to your device.

Comment: Great way to bypass the iTunes restrictions. Do be aware, iTunes will complain and ask to remove the app each time you sync. The other alternative is a jailbreak to bypass these sort of restrictions.

Comment: So then if `jailbreak` and the `iPhone Configuration Utility` are the only ways to install the google+ app, am I right in understanding that the google did not want for us to install google+ on the iPod touch? At least with version 1.0.1

Comment: Only Google knows why. Maybe they don't like the iPod touch? Or they just forgot that it's there?

Comment: Publicly guessing motivation is tricky - there could be intention to roll it out further, but chose to develop and test a limited set of devices initially. Yes - the added test load for testing on iPod isn't as nearly as large as designing and testing a new layout on iPad - it still occupies limited development time, money and resources. Unless someone at google blogs about the decision, we can only watch and wait....

Comment: I have to laugh. I have an iPod touch that downloaded the app just fine. (iOS 7.1.1).

Answer (score 1):

I have the Verizon iPad 2 and it doesn't show up in my app store search at all. Installed fine on my iPhone 4